# equally space the line and dots in react native

Tags: flexbox, react-native, react-native-ios

[image: IMG]

In the screenshot, I want to equally space the lines and dots. How to do it.

I have added following as my styling

```
verticalProgressLine: {   //styling for line
  flex: 1,
  width: 4, 
  alignSelf: 'center'
},
statusIconStyle: {   //styling for right icon
  height: 28,
  width: 28, 
},
statusIconSmallStyle: {   //styling for dots
  height: 12,
  width: 12,
  top: 10, //added because i need equal space as above
},
```

Suggestions please

Comment: take a look at this and see if it can be helpful to you: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/

Comment: Tried, didn't got any success

Answer (score 0):

maybe for statusIconSmallStyle using border with transparent color instead of top be more reasonable:

```
statusIconSmallStyle: {   //styling for dots
  height: 12,
  width: 12,
  border:"solid 4px transparent"
},
```